# Authorizes web app script on user behalf without giving user access to the google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, authorization

I made a web app using google app script for customer support department that reads and writes to a google sheet table, in order to know who is that add or edit i made the script run on behalf of the user, so i can use the Session.getActiveUser() to identify the user, the problem for me is that in this approach i also give the user access to the sheet directly which is not so good because i made the app to be able to give them much simpler ui and with limited ability to change the data i dont wont the user to be able to delete or change other users input. is there a way to limit access to the sheet itself? or my approach is all wrong?

Comment: Your quesiton is too general to give a specific answer, but there many things you can do - for example you can set up sheets or range [protections](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) on the sheet that would allow certain users access to only certain data.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a simple google form for this? I know a web app might be nicer and more flexible but if you can accomplish your goal with a google form (which writes directly to the sheet) you can just collect their email address.

Comment: I know the form is great option but not in this case, the app abilities to sort & edit with custom validations is superior to a form.